# Empty array in PHP with MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to code it so users can type in their -- or others -- usernames which will be converted in their UUID then returns that user's stats from my MySql databse.

The code I attempted this with is

```
$username = $_POST['searchbox'];
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/".$username);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$id = $obj->id;
$rank = Database::query("SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE uuid=:uuid", array(':uuid'=>"".$id))[0]['rank'];
echo 'Showing results for '.$_POST['searchbox'].' '.$id.' Rank: '.$rank;
```

Except when I run this code it outputs:

> "Showing results for kingbluesapphire 0d8d246d11c54cbbb197c6bc8ba01ee2 Rank:"

I know it's not a problem with the connection to the database because other queries are working

My goal right now is to get the field in the MySql Database thats called rank and I would like to display their rank.

Comment: `print_r` to see what does `Database::query` return? Most probably it's not returning resulting array, it must be return resultset. In that case loop over resultset to get player `rank` from 1st index of result array.

Comment: @HamzaRashid when i "print_r($rank);" it doesn't print out anything

Comment: `print_r(Database::query("SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE uuid=:uuid", array(':uuid'=>"".$id)));` Do this and see what's result?

Comment: @HamzaRashid now it prints out "Array ( )"

Comment: So, is there any `playerdata` in the database with this id `0d8d246d11c54cbbb197c6bc8ba01ee2` ?

Comment: Now go one step up and check what does `print_r(json_decode($json))` return?

Comment: @JorgeCampos In the database it seems to be '0d8d246d-11c5-4cbb-b197-c6bc8ba01ee2'

Comment: So either you have to find out what is removing the dashes or chage your query to `... WHERE replace(uuid, '-','')=:uuid`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks, now it works!

Comment: I will add it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the discussion in the comments, either you have to find out what is removing the dashes **which I highly recomend to** or change your query to:

```
$rank = Database::query("SELECT * 
                           FROM playerdata 
                          WHERE replace(uuid, '-','')=:uuid",
                        array(':uuid'=>"".$id))[0]['rank'];
```

Databases need to be given the exact value you are looking for, any different character in a equals operation will not give you any data.

Comment: Just wondering is there a better way if I'm trying to get multiple fields example a "rank" field and "money" field.so i run 2 of those queries ones with rank and one with money?

Comment: Are those fields in the `playerdata` table? If yes you just need to fetch that fields since you are already selecting then all with `select *` I'm not sure what are you using but it should be `$rank["name_of_the_field_you_want"]` that of course will depends on what `$rank` is returning. See it as `print_r($rank)` after the execution of the query.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['searchbox']){
  $sb = $_POST['searchbox']);
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/$sb"));
  if($queryRes = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE uuid={$json->id}")){
    if($queryRes->num_rows){
      $o = $queryRes->fetch_object(); // guessing there's only one row or you would put this in a while loop
      echo "Showing results for $sb {$o->uuid} Rank:{$o->rank}";
    }
  }
  else{
    die($connection->connect_error);
  }
}
?>
```

I'm assuming `uuid` is a number. Do tell.